# How to permit params by action and current user role in Rails with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

My app allows some users to create products using `Pundit`. But these users do **not** have the same `permitted params`.

I can't delete the keys because the logic is very complex and it's hard to read.

How can I permit the params by their role? What is the best way to do it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
def user_params
  list_allowed = [:email, :title, :last_name, :first_name, :phone]
  list_allowed << :role << other_param << another_param if current_user.admin?
  params.require(:user).permit(list_allowed)
end
```